# React: playNote() Undefined Function Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'll be short, I'm trying to make an piano application that will play notes on mouse click in the first stage of app, later on I want to do that on keyboard buttons. So I have the problem I don't know if I am calling a function properly or even if I'm doing forEach loop properly.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react'
import NoteA from './notes/A.mp3';
import NoteAb from './notes/Ab.mp3';
import NoteB from './notes/B.mp3';
import NoteBb from './notes/Bb.mp3';
import NoteC from './notes/C.mp3';
import NoteD from './notes/D.mp3';
import NoteDb from './notes/Db.mp3';
import NoteE from './notes/E.mp3';
import NoteEb from './notes/Eb.mp3';
import NoteF from './notes/F.mp3';
import NoteG from './notes/G.mp3';
import NoteGb from './notes/Gb.mp3';

const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');
keys.forEach(key => {
    key.addEventListener('click', () => playNote(key));
})


class Piano extends Component {

    playNote = (key) => {
        const noteAudio = document.getElementById(key.dataset.note);
        noteAudio.play();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <div class="piano">
                <div data-note="C" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="Db" class="key black"></div>
                <div data-note="D" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="Eb" class="key black"></div>
                <div data-note="E" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="F" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="Gb" class="key black"></div>
                <div data-note="G" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="Ab" class="key black"></div>
                <div data-note="A" class="key white"></div>
                <div data-note="Bb" class="key black"></div>
                <div data-note="B" class="key white"></div>
            </div>

            <audio id="C" src="../notes/C.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Db" src="../notes/Db.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="D" src="../notes/D.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Eb" src="../notes/Eb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="E" src="../notes/E.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="F" src="../notes/F.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Gb" src="../notes/Gb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="G" src="../notes/G.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Ab" src="../notes/Ab.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="A" src="../notes/A.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Bb" src="../notes/Bb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="B" src="../notes/B.mp3"></audio>

            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Piano
```

P.S. I am new to React, I was watching an tutorial on YouTube, guy did this type of application with Vanilla JavaScript so I wanted to try if I can make it through React.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to attach click listener outside component. Do right inside jsx/html

```js
class Piano extends Component {

    playNote = (id) => {
        const noteAudio = document.getElementById(id);
        noteAudio.play();
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
            <div class="piano">
                <div data-note="C" className="key white" onClick={() => this.playNote('C')}></div>
                <div data-note="Db" className="key black" onClick={() => this.playNote('Db')}></div>
                
            </div>

            <audio id="C" src="../notes/C.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Db" src="../notes/Db.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="D" src="../notes/D.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Eb" src="../notes/Eb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="E" src="../notes/E.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="F" src="../notes/F.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Gb" src="../notes/Gb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="G" src="../notes/G.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Ab" src="../notes/Ab.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="A" src="../notes/A.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="Bb" src="../notes/Bb.mp3"></audio>
            <audio id="B" src="../notes/B.mp3"></audio>

            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Piano
```

Comment: You could also just pass along the event from the `onClick` and get the id using `e.target.getAttribute("data-note")`

Comment: That's possible but just wanted to make it more clearer for OP

Comment: Fair enough. Just something for OP to thing about to make the code a bit cleaner

Comment: I think I did wrong, const keys I typed an '.key' class and down here I have put a class only as a div attribute, but React demands className, maybe error is in there?

Comment: You are right @ravenousHydra. Fix your code. I'll update mine

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Lol, I have now different type of error: index.js:1 Uncaught Error: The error you provided does not contain a stack trace. UPDATE: I have read a little about this error, and I have found an answer that I need to put it inside a variable and try to put it inside if/else statement

Answer (score 0):

Use refs since you use React. Use it in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
        //Set event listeners for keypress
        window.addEventListener("keyup", this.keyPress);
}
```

Where event listener has callback method who plays sound by engaging audio's by ref. 
[Ref docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

I've done it something similar from FCC curriculum: [DrumMachine](https://codepen.io/codename11/pen/qJEbLw)